# How can I use caps lock to change language in VIM

Tags: vim

Can I use caps lock for changing language in VIM intead of Ctrl-6 in case of keymap=russian-jcukenwin?

How can I do it?

Maybe smth like mapping in $VIMRC file? How can I map caps lock? Is it possible?

Comment: You can't do it from within Vim because it doesn't "get" the Caps Lock key. But you can probably remap that key to some other key system-wide and use that key to create a mapping in Vim. But we don't even know what OS you use.

Comment: Duplicate question on http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93975/how-can-i-use-caps-lock-to-change-language-in-vim; please don't spam multiple sites with the identical question!

Answer (score 2):

The <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> is a special key; it cannot be mapped in Vim itself. But if you use operating system-specific means / tools to remap that key to another (unused, e.g. `<F13>`, which rarely exists on a keyboard) one, you can use that key in an ordinary Vim mapping.